# Custom Metadata Update does not run QueuebleHandler in Metadata.DeployCallback when called from extended Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass

Tags: metadata, custom-metadata, authproviderpluginclass

I am trying to update a Custom Metadata record using the following code, which works perfectly well when run as an Anonymous user through the development console:

```
public class SageMetaDeploy implements Metadata.DeployCallback{


    private List<FieldWrapper> listField{get;set;}

    public class FieldWrapper
    {
        public String fieldName {get; set;}
        public String fieldAPIName {get; set;}
    } 
    

    public static string updateCustomMetadata(String refreshToken)
    {
        system.debug('*** Updating Meta: ' + refreshToken);

        Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata = new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        customMetadata.fullName = 'Sage_Credentials_Defenition.SageAuth'; //custom metadata name
        customMetadata.label = 'SageAuth';

        Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField1 = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue(); //the values you're changing/updating
        customField1.field = 'Refresh_Token__c'; //the custom field API Name that you're wanting to insert/update a value of
        customField1.value = refreshToken;//refreshToken;
        customMetadata.values.add(customField1);//add the changes to list of changes to be deployed


        try {
            Sage_Credentials_Defenition__mdt scd = getMetaDataRecords()[0]; //retrieving custom metadata records, using the first.
            Id customMetadataId = scd.Id;
            system.debug('CustomMetadata Id ' + customMetadataId);

            Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
            mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
        
            SageMetaDeploy callback = new SageMetaDeploy();
                      
            Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
            
            system.debug('jobId is ' + jobId);
            
           return 'Success';
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    return e.getMessage();
            }
     }

    public static list<Sage_Credentials_Defenition__mdt> getMetaDataRecords()
    {
        list<Sage_Credentials_Defenition__mdt> smd = [Select Id, label FROM Sage_Credentials_Defenition__mdt];
        return smd;
    }
       
    
    // find all sObjects available in the organization
    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result, Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {

        system.debug('Meta Update Result Handler');

        if(result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.SUCCEEDED)
        {
            //success
            System.debug(' ===>'+ result);
        }else{
            //not success
            System.debug(' ===> fail '+ result);
        }
        
    }
}
```

However, when it is called from

```
Public with sharing class SageAuthProvider extends Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass {
...

  public Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse handleCallback(Map<String,String> authProviderConfiguration, Auth.AuthProviderCallbackState state) {
            
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'handleCallback-callbackState: ' + state);
        
        Map<String,String> queryParams = state.queryParameters; 
        String sfdcState = queryParams.get('state'); 
        final String httpBody = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + queryParams.get('code');

        system.debug('sfdcState: ' + sfdcState);
        system.debug('Code from Query Params: ' + httpBody);          

        SageResponse token = GetToken(authProviderConfiguration, httpBody, 'GET');

        system.debug('Meta Data Refresh token value: ' + authProviderConfiguration.get('Refresh_Token__c'));
        system.debug('Refresh token returning: ' + token.refresh_token);
      
        
        String result = SageMetaDeploy.updateCustomMetadata(token.refresh_token);        

        return new Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse(authProvider, token.access_token, token.refresh_token, sfdcState);         
    } 
}
```

- it does not seem to enqueue deployment on line **Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);** in SageMetaDeploy class even though the jobId is generated.  I don't see this log in the dev console.
  [image: Dev console log]

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: didi you look in setup > Apex Jobs to see if some error was encountered?

Comment: @cropredy thx for your response. there are no logs in Apex Jobs when this runs successfully or fails. I should mention that when it fails, no exceptions or error logs are left anywhere.